# Loopback interface is renamed to rename1

Tags: ubuntu, udev

On my Ubuntu 17.04 Server the Loopback Interface keeps beeing renamed to "rename1" during boot (Syslog: `rename1: renamed from lo`).

I tried to disabling renaming by editing grub.conf: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"`

I have no files in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.

`ifconfig` outputs the following:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      ...
rename1: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8  bytes 544 (544.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8  bytes 544 (544.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

How can I permanently change the name of the loopback interface to `lo`?

My `/etc/network/interfaces` conatins the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Check for the `ifrename` package, if there is, simply uninstalling it may be also a solution.

Comment: There is no such package installed.

Comment: I would do `grep -r rename1 /etc` and the offending file will probably show up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in `/etc/network/interfaces` I'm not sure if 17.04 keeps it there but that's where its been in the past.

Comment: Not sure what I should change there. In my `interfaces` I have the configuration for `lo`, but it doesn't work (see updated Question).

Answer (score 0):

So, just in case someone else hits this: I just encountered this issue. As with other people who have seen it, my config files were all fine. The problem was ultimately do to an out of date initramfs; updating the initramfs (with `update-initramfs -u`) fixed my problem.